# Bootstrap collapsable panel not opening - no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a panel to house an optional search form form an index page in my Rails 5 App. Currently I am using Bootstrap 3 as my framework.

The panel is built (here it is)

```
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= render partial: 'users/search_form/search_form' %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It appears on the page, however when I click it to open it, it doesn't do anything.

I have gone over the bootstrap 3 rails integration process a few times and i dont see any issues with it.

here is my application.scss file (and ive tried renaming it to css.scss as some other posts have suggested but that did not fix it.

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";
```

here is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Not too sure where i'm going wrong with this any help here would be great.

Comment: Do you mean that your form does not appear or do you mean that the panel does not open?

Comment: @PragyakarJoshi - the Panel dose not open

Comment: It seems to be the whole collapsable content thats not working. I have tried the button toggle, accordion and now the panel they all appear but just wont open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to be working. Did you not meant that when you click 'Collapsible panel', the hidden panel should appear. Please recheck. It works fine when you click the 'Collapsible panel' text. If you want your panel to appear when the whole box where 'Collapsible panel' is written then simply move the 'a' tag to before the panel-heading class. Like this:

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Collapsible panel
                </h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= render partial: 'users/search_form/search_form' %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: no no, the text, when i click it, dose nothing. thats all i want for the link for the time being.

Comment: have you included 
'<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: I copied your exact code and it worked fine. Please check all the necessary bootstrap  and jQuery links. Maybe there is a problem there. Besides that the code seems fine. :)